# Python whats the most efficient way to wait for input

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a python program I want to run in the background (on a Raspberry Pi) that waits for GPIO input then performs an action and continues waiting for input until the process is killed.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this. My understanding is that using while true is not so efficient.  Ideally it would use interrupts - and I could use GPIO.wait_for_edge - but that would need to be in some loop or way of continuing operation upon completion of the handler.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain a bit more why `while True:` `x = GPIO.wait_for_edge()` `if hasSomeProperty(x): break` is no suitable solution for your case.

Comment: @Alfe I'm new to python - so not exactly sure how efficient a `while True:` is.  My assumption is that it used cpu - looping around.  I was wondering if there is some other construct that would just wait (using no cpu), much like `GPIO.wait_for_edge()` but not GPIO specific  - then allowing the interrupt handlers do their respective processing.   This is for a service/background task that would just run continually - waiting for interrupt.  I just don't it chewing up cpu if it's doing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

According to this:  http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING) will wait for a transition on pin 23 using interrupts instead of polling.  It'll only continue when triggered.  You can enclose it in a try: / except KeyboardInterrupt to catch ctrl-c.

If you want to continue processing then you should register a call back function for your interrupt.  See:  http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/

```
def callback(channel):
   do something here

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)
continue your program here, likely in some sort of state machine
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark - I saw that article.. but I want it to continue processing. And I was assuming that putting it in a `while True` loop was inefficient.  Also I would prefer to use interrupts.

Comment: Gotcha -- I edited my answer to include a callback function.  The code will execute that function in a second thread alongside your main state machine when a trigger is detected.

Comment: Thanks @Mark - yeah that's the line of thought I was on.  So what is the most efficient way to implement the "continue..." part?  Either with a state machine or without. If using a state machine, I assume some kind of loop is required that constantly checks for state change - which I assume would chew up CPU even when no change is present (which would be most of the time).

Comment: Yes I think you will always need a loop to just keep the program alive.  But you can have it sleep for some time which will cut down on CPU usage dramatically.  Depending on what you need to do in your loop and what your callback implements your sleep time can be 10 ms, 1 second, 10 seconds, etc.

Comment: Thanks - yeah that's what it's looking like.  I was rather hoping you could just do an infinite sleep - and let the interrupts do the work.  I've read a few articles talking about polling vs interrupts... but if you've having to loop anyway (when using interrupts) - then whats there's little difference in polling?  So do all services use a while loop with a sleep?

Comment: If you want to go to infinite sleep then you can't do anything else, so you might as well use wait_for_edge.  The difference of polling vs interrupts is speed.  If you are polling then you're only checking your pin's state once every loop.  That might be fine for lighting an LED based on the state of a switch.  But if you want to make an oscilloscope trigger then you need to be ready to acquire data within say 1 microsecond of the trigger occurring.  The interrupt executes your callback as soon as is possible within the limitations of the hardware and OS.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that when you say "using while true" you mean polling,
which is checking the gpio state at some time interval to detect
changes, in the expense of some processing time.

One alternative to avoid polling (from the [docs](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/)) is wait_for_edge():

> The wait_for_edge() function is designed to block execution of your program
>   until an edge is detected.

Which seems to be what you are looking for; the program would suspend
execution using [epool()](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/event_gpio.c) IIUC.

Now assuming you meant that you don't want to use GPIO.wait_for_edge()
because you don't want to loose GPIO state changes while handling
events, you'll need to use threading. One possible solution is putting
events in a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue), and setup:

- One thread to do the `while True: queue.put(GPIO.wait_for_edge(...))`.
- Another thread to perform the `Queue.get()`.

Comment: Thanks @jvdm Good idea (about using a Queue). although to my original question - is a `while True:` loop efficient.  I'm starting to get the feel that it is the only approach based on what I've read.  Would be interesting to find out exactly what `GPIO_wait_for_edge()` does under the hood (ie does it also do a `while` loop).    Does anyone know how a GUI python app stays running while waiting for input?

Comment: ``while True`` loop efficiency depends on what the body of the loop is doing, if you use ``wait_for_edge()``, it will suspend the thread waiting for I/O events from a file descriptor using ``epoll()`` (according to the source code cited in the answer).